# How to dynamically render XML in Grails?

Tags: xml, grails, dynamic, groovy

I'm setting up an application that initiates phone calls based on XML files specific to each call instance. For testing purposes, I was using the Groovy MarkupBuilder and StringWriter methods to write my XMLs to a single file, and then overwrite that file the next time a call was initiated.

However, this will not work in production, because we will be overwriting XML that is currently in use. So, I'd like to dynamically create XML in a controller by calling it with something like:

```
callInstance.createXml()
```

with the "createXml" method containing the rules for how to render the XML specifically for each call.

I've found multiple instances of people asking how to turn an object into a dynamically created XML file, but this is a little different since I'm having to use the MarkupBuilder.

For a quick reference, here's small example of what I'm working with:

```
def f1 = new File('filename')
f1.delete()
def writer = new StringWriter()
        def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
            xml.doubleQuotes = true
            xml.vxml(version:'2.1'){
                property(name:"termchar", value:"#")
                var(name:"hi", expr:"'Hello!'")
                xml.form(){
                    block(){
                        value(expr:"hi")
                        xml.goto(next:"#next") //etc, etc
                    }
                }
            }
        //break
        f1.createNewFile()
            f1 << writer.toString()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-grails09168/)?  3 years old, but it still has some good info in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do (in your controller) is to [send the XML back from the render method](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.7%20XML%20and%20JSON%20Responses) like so:

```
def callxml = {
  def call = Call.get( params.id )
  render( contentType:"text/xml" ) {
    vxml( version:'2.1' ) {
      var( name:'hi', expr:call.message )
    }
  }
}
```

Or, you could add a method to the Call class, so it knows how to convert itself to XML as a String:

```
class Call {
  String message

  String toXml() {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder( writer ).with { xml ->
      xml.doubleQuotes = true
      vxml(version:'2.1'){
        var(name:"hi", expr:"${this.message}")
      }
    }
    writer.toString()
  }
}
```

Then you should be able to call `call.toXml()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm not trying to print the output to the log, I'm trying to render the text so I can pass parameters to the function, so I don't think this will work. I'm looking for a function that I can call on a call instance to input the parameters of the call instance into the generated XML. ie: <var name="hi" expr="${call.message}" />

Comment: @Benjamin changed my response, hopefully I'm closer to what you mean now :-)

Comment: So, if I were to tackle this the first way, it would allow me to point an external application at the hosted action? eg: http://localhost:8080/project/controller/callxml? Right now, I'm directing a call to be placed based on a hosted xml file. Will this behave the same way? I'm sorry, I'm very new to this!

Comment: Yeah, you would be able to read the xml for a given call by pointing to:  `localhost:8080/project/controller/callxml?id=2` to get the xml for call #2 for example.  You can make the URL neater in the `UrlMappings.groovy` file too by specifying the position of the id parameter in the url

Comment: You can also hook up a Marshaller so that you can do: `render call as XML`.  I've never tried this, but [there's some info on this page](http://omaha-seattle.blogspot.com/2010/02/grails-xml-conversion.html)